# Returning position an object based on nested property value

Tags: arrays, search, ecmascript-6

Been racking my brains trying to figure this one out.  I have an object model of users. Nested in the object is a property called roles - which is an array of roles - as per below:

```
0: {…}
​​
createdAt: "2020-09-15T22:23:18.551Z"
​​
id: "5f16c3781f2bc30ad20452c8"
​​
roles: Array [ "Owner" ]
​​
updatedAt: "2020-09-15T22:23:18.551Z"
​​
user: Object { id: "5f16c3781f2bc30ad20452c8", nodeId: "5f16c3781f2bc30ad20452c8", username: "John smith", … }
​​
​
1: {…}
​​
createdAt: "2020-10-20T11:09:07.395Z"
​​
id: "5ea683231fac57758ae7e4e2"
​​
roles: Array [ "Member" ]
​​
updatedAt: "2020-10-20T11:09:07.395Z"
​​
user: Object { id: "5ea683231fac57758ae7e4e2", nodeId: "MDQ6VXNlcjI1MTc0ODQ=", username: "monstertrux", … }
```

I am trying to return the index position of the user that has the role `Owner`.
I have tried all sorts of ways to do it with no luck.
Best I could do was
`let projOwner = membertempArray.indexOf(item => (item.roles.filter( role => role === 'Owner')`
to return the index value, but if just fails - returns -1.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`tab.findIndex(item=>item.roles.includes('Owner'))`